# extract json in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
id   | status | outgoing
-------------------------
1    | paid   | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing","old.a945248027_14454878":"cancelled"}
2    | pending| {"069e5248cf_45299995":"processing"}
```

I am trying to extract the values after each underscore in the outgoing column e.g from `a945248027_14454878` I want `14454878`

Because the json data is not standardised I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What if there were two different keys in the row with ID = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the json key part after the underscore using regexp version of `substring`.

```sql
select id, status, outgoing,
       substring(key from '_([^_]+)$') as key
from the_table, lateral jsonb_object_keys(outgoing) as j(key);
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kF2QdhpyaTSua1286jcbfq/0).